# What is the return URL for Azure AD B2C Mobile Flow for my Ionic Cordova App?

Tags: azure, cordova, azure-ad-b2c, ionic5

Ok, so I am wiring up my Ionic Cordova mobile app to use Azure AD B2C. Doing a simple `window.location.href = "https://xxx.b2clogin.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=xxx&client_id=123&nonce=..."` while testing in the browser (`ionic start`) locally, I'm redirected to Azure AD to handle logging in.

I'm then redirected back to `https://localhost:4200/auth` and it works locally but what about on the device? What should the callback endpoint be? How do I determine this?

MSAL - [Mobile App Sign-in Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-sign-in-flow#desktop-and-mobile-app-sign-in-flow) --> Gives no guidance on the above...